# Alpine Installation with preseed cfg

Tags: preseed, alpine-linux

I would like to install Alpine using preseed.cfg. However, I cannot find one online. 
Does alpine support preseed in the first place? If yes, is it possible to edit another preseed and adopt it for Alpine? For example I have a debian preseed, but I see that some options are debian specific. Example:

```
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
```

Comment: preseeding is a Debian specific functionality...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Many distributions have a similar feature, whether they call it “preseeding” or not (e.g. kickstart on RHEL).

Comment: I am aware of kickstart, thanks @Gilles . I am not that familiar with Alpine besides knowing it is a (very) stripped down distro, mainly used in Docker and embedded/iOT devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine Linux does not support preseed since it's a debian-only feature, which integrates with debian-installer.
Anyway, Alpine does support what is called an "unattended" installation.
You should provide an "answerfile" to setup-alpine script.
More info can be found here: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_setup_scripts

Comment: If you come to this question now I can recommend reading Mr Colista's updated and excellent answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536486/136152.